# WSO2 Identity Server 5.11.0 startup issue

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I have been testing Wso2 Identity Server. I have set it as key manager to wso2 api manager `4.0.0`. Everything was working fine unless I restarted wso2 api manager. First, after restarting wso2 api manager the error with following stacktrace appeared:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-08-08 11:14:22,305] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing} - [SCR] Exception occurred while unbinding reference Reference[name = registry.service, interface = org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.service.RegistryService, policy = dynamic, cardinality = 1..1, target = null, bind = setRegistryService, unbind = unsetRegistryService]
        Details:
        Problematic reference = Reference[name = registry.service, interface = org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.service.RegistryService, policy = dynamic, cardinality = 1..1, target = null, bind = setRegistryService, unbind = unsetRegistryService]
        of service component = org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing
        component implementation class = org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.internal.IndexingServiceComponent
        located in bundle with symbolic name = org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing
        bundle location = reference:file:../plugins/org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing_4.7.39.jar java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor64.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ComponentReference.unbind(ComponentReference.java:476)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.unbindReference(ServiceComponentProp.java:617)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.unbind(ServiceComponentProp.java:262)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:350)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.buildNewlySatisfied(Resolver.java:473)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.enableComponents(Resolver.java:217)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.performWork(SCRManager.java:816)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager$QueuedJob.dispatch(SCRManager.java:783)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.WorkThread.run(WorkThread.java:89)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.util.impl.tpt.threadpool.Executor.run(Executor.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.RegistryConfigLoader
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.IndexingManager.<init>(IndexingManager.java:60)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.IndexingManager.getInstance(IndexingManager.java:71)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.internal.IndexingServiceComponent.stopIndexing(IndexingServiceComponent.java:128)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.internal.IndexingServiceComponent.unsetRegistryService(IndexingServiceComponent.java:123)
        ... 15 more
```

I thought it was related to identity server, then I restarted wso2 identity server as well, but then I have received following error:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-08-08 06:42:44,291] [] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat} - error while parsing xml stream org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 37; columnNumber: 93; Error at line [37] column [93]: [org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:1902)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:1934)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1223)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1495)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat.configure(CarbonTomcat.java:90)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.ServerManager.init(ServerManager.java:156)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.TomcatBundleActivator.start(TomcatBundleActivator.java:40)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:842)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:834)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:791)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1013)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:365)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:598)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:462)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$1.run(ModuleContainer.java:1820)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$2$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1813)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1770)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1735)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1661)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.ContextFinder.loadClass(ContextFinder.java:139)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:104)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1220)
        ... 32 more
```

I would like to have them working intact

Comment: Are you running on Windows?

Comment: @ycr having the same error with APIM 4.2 and default Key Manager (no IS). Everything worked fine before restart

Comment: additionally, in my logs I see a lot of errors related to unresolved module/dependencies like: FrameworkEvent ERROR org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework

Answer (score 4):

This WSO2 IS/APIM startup failure encounters when using the latest JDK versions 11 (JDK 11.0.20) and 17 (JDK 17.0.8+9). This is due to a fix that has been implemented by JDK [1].

According to the JDK release notes [2] [3], we can disable these newly introduced validations to preserve backward compatibility. These validations can be disabled by adding the following.

**Linux / MacOS Users:**

Include the provided lines below after the line: "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true " in either:

`wso2server.sh` for WSO2 Identity Server and API Manager versions prior to 4.0.0, or
`api-manager.sh` for WSO2 API Manager versions 4.0.0 and later.

```
-Djdk.util.zip.disableZip64ExtraFieldValidation=true \
-Djdk.nio.zipfs.allowDotZipEntry=true \
```

**Windows Users:**

Append the provided parameters below to the CMD_LINE_ARGS parameter (at the end of the line starting with "set CMD_LINE_ARGS") in either:

`wso2server.bat` for WSO2 Identity Server and API Manager versions prior to 4.0.0, or
`api-manager.bat` for WSO2 API Manager versions 4.0.0 and later.

```
-Djdk.util.zip.disableZip64ExtraFieldValidation=true 
-Djdk.nio.zipfs.allowDotZipEntry=true
```

[1] - https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8251329

[2] - https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/11-0-20-relnotes.html

[3] - https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/17all-relnotes.html

Comment: When we initially encountered this we rolled back to Java version 11.0.19.  We now went to implement this fix to allow the Java version to update.  It appears, from our testing so far, that while WSO APIM breaks with Java version 11.0.20 (unless you apply this fix), there is no problem with an out-of-the-box APIM when using Java version 11.0.21.  Can you confirm that Java version 11.0.21 does not require this work-round?  Is it recommended to apply this anyway or not?  We are using APIM version 4.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Seems issue with the latest Java path.

We use Java 11 with our WSO2APIM and after the latest system upgrade newer version of Java was installed - 11.0.**20**. That patch broke WSO.
We rolled back to 11.0.**19** and it started to work again